# numbers greater or equal condition

Tags: luatex, tex-core

can't believe that there is a language in which such a simple thing requires so much effort.

well i want to do a `greater or equal to` comparison of an argument in a macro. My current try is not right.

here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{metropolis}}

\usepackage{tikz}
 
\NewDocumentCommand\putlabel{ O{1} }{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) (base) {base};
  \ifnum#1=1\relax\else\ifnum#1>1\relax
    \node at (base.south) (premier) [anchor=north] {au moins un};
  \fi\fi

  \ifnum#1=2\relax\else\ifnum#1>2\relax
    \node at (premier.south) (deuxieme) [anchor=north] {au moins deux};
  \fi\fi

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
  \putlabel[1]
\dots
  \putlabel[2]
\dots
  \putlabel[3]
\dots
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifnum1>#1\relax`  tests if #1 is greater than or equal to 1

Comment: it's two tests each time to make it behave like ">="

Comment: No it's one test, as I showed. `\ifnum1>#1\relax not greater than equal to1\else greater than or equal to 1\fi`

Comment: i meant, in my mwe, that is what i tried to do but as i wrote it there, my try is not right

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your first comment and second comment, are they saying the same thing?

Comment: yes but you didn't seem to understand the first one so I expanded it a bit and re-posted

Comment: @DavidCarlisle (one main dev in latex IFAIK) `\ifnum1>#1\relax` and `\ifnum1>#1\relax ... \else ...\fi` if here you claim that these two statements are the same then i understand why i always spent huge effort in achieving anything in LaTeX. And, your first solution, i implemented it as it is in my mwe, it does not work.

Comment: they look the same test to me,  obviously if you have `\if...` you need to fill in the `...` with the rest of the code of the form `yes\else no\fi`, I thought that was clear but seemed not so I filled in the code in the  second version. Make sure you have the code in the right branch of course. as `>` has changed to `<`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a macro `\?` with usage:

```
\ifnum number\? >= number\relax
```

or

```
\ifnum number\? <= number\relax
```

It can be defined like this:

```
\def\?#1#2#3\relax{\ifx#1>>\numexpr#3-1\else<\numexpr#3+1\fi\relax}
```

Tests:

```
\def\?#1#2#3\relax{\ifx#1>>\numexpr#3-1\else<\numexpr#3+1\fi\relax}

\def\test#1{\ifnum #1\? >= 1\relax yes, #1>=1\else no, #1<1\fi}

\test 0 \par \test 1 \par \test 2

\def\test#1{\ifnum #1\? <= 1\relax yes, #1<=1\else no, #1>1\fi}

\test 0 \par \test 1 \par \test 2

\bye
```

But I understand that you will say that this is somewhat tricky. Unfortunately TeX doesn't support `\ifnum` with `<=` and `>=` at primitive level because the author of TeX expected that programmers are able to use the negation, if it is needed.

Comment: well you said it. up vote!

Answer (score 3):

The test for the *integer* `#1` to be greater than or equal to 1 is

```
\ifnum#1>0
```

and similarly for 2.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{metropolis}}

\NewDocumentCommand\putlabel{ O{1} }{% <--- don't forget
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) (base) {base};
  \ifnum#1>0
    \node at (base.south) (premier) [anchor=north] {au moins un};
  \fi

  \ifnum#1>1
    \node at (premier.south) (deuxieme) [anchor=north] {au moins deux};
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}% <--- don't forget
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{test}

\putlabel[1] \dots \putlabel[2] \dots \putlabel[3] \dots

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{metropolis}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\intCompareTF}{mmm}
 {% #1 = condition, #2 = true text, #3 = false text
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand\putlabel{ O{1} }{% <--- don't forget
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) (base) {base};
  \intCompareTF{#1>=1}{\node at (base.south) (premier) [anchor=north] {au moins un};}{}
  \intCompareTF{#1>=2}{\node at (premier.south) (deuxieme) [anchor=north] {au moins deux};}{}
  \end{tikzpicture}% <--- don't forget
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{test}

\putlabel[1] \dots \putlabel[2] \dots \putlabel[3] \dots

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you expect the argument to be a floating point number, you can use `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{metropolis}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpCompareTF}{mmm}
 {% #1 = condition, #2 = true text, #3 = false text
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand\putlabel{ O{1} }{% <--- don't forget
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) (base) {base};
  \fpCompareTF{#1>=1}{\node at (base.south) (premier) [anchor=north] {au moins un};}{}
  \fpCompareTF{#1>=2}{\node at (premier.south) (deuxieme) [anchor=north] {au moins deux};}{}
  \end{tikzpicture}% <--- don't forget
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{test}

\putlabel[1.1] \dots \putlabel[2] \dots \putlabel[2.1] \dots

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output will be the same.

Comment: i know we can decrement by one the number against which we test, but that's a trick. I also know there is expl3. Can you implement literally without any trick `>=`, `<=`

Comment: @user1850133 Isn't that what `\fpCompareTF` is doing? Why doesn't `expl3` count?

Comment: @user1850133  integer arithmetic `a>=b  yes no` is just `b<a  no yes` as I already commented  under the question. That's nothing to do with latex, just basic arithmetic.

Comment: @user1850133 I added the integer comparison.

Answer (score 2):

As commented under the question a>=b is just the negation of b<a so the following is an alternative form, producing the same output as egreg showed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{metropolis}}

\NewDocumentCommand\putlabel{ O{1} }{% <--- don't forget
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) (base) {base};
  \ifnum1>#1\relax\else
    \node at (base.south) (premier) [anchor=north] {au moins un};
  \fi

  \ifnum2>#1\relax\else
    \node at (premier.south) (deuxieme) [anchor=north] {au moins deux};
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}% <--- don't forget
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{test}

\putlabel[1] \dots \putlabel[2] \dots \putlabel[3] \dots

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: looking at your corrosive comment i think you're the one who down-voted my question. Keep cool and think again. After all you took time to provide many inputs and a solution

Comment: @user1850133 huh????  I didn't downvote and the comment wasnt intended to be critical at all. I had thought the first comment would have been enough to solve your problem, it seemed I abbreviated it too much for you to follow so I reposted an expanded form. your response was rather unexpected and bizarre,  but whatever. This answer is just the application of the initial comment to your example.

Comment: i'm talking of the "you didn't seem to understand..."

Comment: @user1850133 you asked why I posted the comment in two forms. I posted the second as you didn't understand the initial comment which was very abbreviated, so I posted an expanded form. it wasn't critical, just a fact that you asked for????